# Mongo DB as service on Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I installed MongoDB on Ubuntu 14.04 using this [tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/). Everything works fine, but how can I run it as service not only manualy?

To make it more clear: I want that MongoDB keeps running after I close "ssh shell".

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mongodb`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to install it via APT

Step 1: Import public key

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Step 2: Add the MongoDB repository details so APT

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

Then update APT packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3: Installing and Verifying MongoDB

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Verify it status

```
service mongod status
```

It should show: `mongod start/running, process 1611`

You can also stop, start, and restart MongoDB using the service command (e.g. `service mongod stop`, `server mongod start`).

> References: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: what's wrong with the version in the default repository? (`apt-get install mongodb`)